# Verify Pseudo-Random Data in C

Tags: c, random, io, openmp

I am writing a disk exerciser program and I want to be able to generate some random data to fill a buffer, write it out to disk, and then verify that the data is 'correct' once it is read back into memory.

The reason I want to generate random data is so that there are different bit patterns getting written to the disk. Currently I am filling the buffer with a single character repeatedly.

```
    buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
    for(i=0;i<buffer_size;i++)
    {
          buf[i] = 'W';
    }
```

The writeData function that repeatedly writes the buffer with 'W' until the filesize is reached:

```
    void* writeData(Data *data) 
    {
        int i,
        j,
        tid;

         double bytes=0,
            start=0,
            stop=0,
            totalTime=0,
            mbPerSec=0;

         double iterations = data->file_size/data->buffer_size;

         #pragma omp parallel for private(tid,start,stop,bytes,totalTime) reduction(+:mbPerSec)
         for(i=0;i<data->num_threads;i++)
         {  
              tid = omp_get_thread_num();
              for(j=0;j<iterations;j++)
              { 
               start = omp_get_wtime();
               bytes += write(data->descriptors[tid],data->out_buf,data->buffer_size);
               stop = omp_get_wtime();
               totalTime = totalTime + (stop - start);
              }
              mbPerSec = bytes/MB_MULTIPLIER/totalTime;
         }
         printf("Write %.f MB/secs\n",mbPerSec);    
    }
```

The readData function is similar, but reads from the file descriptor into a buffer. Are there any algorithms or transformations I could run to generate many different bit patterns and then verify them when they are read back into memory? Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefill a buffer using `rand()` with or without using a known seed, write the buffer to disk, read from disk into a second buffer then use `memcmp()` to verify the two buffers still match, rinse and repeat.

```
#define TEST_LEN 512

int i;
char testBuff[TEST_LEN];
char readBuff[TEST_LEN];

srand( time( NULL ) );

for( i = 0; i < TEST_LEN; i++ )
    testBuff[i] = (char)(rand() & 0xFF);

WriteToDisk( testBuff, TEST_LEN );
ReadFromDisk( readBuff, TEST_LEN );

if( memcmp( testBuff, readBuff, TEST_LEN ) )
    printf( "That's not good!\n" );
```

Comment: Not the best idea. With small enough buffer the data could reside in the devices or OS's cache.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I would not be worried about cache in this case because I am writing/reading the data using the O_DSYNC flag so that the system call doesn't return until the data exists on the disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rand()` function to write random values to the disk. But remember to set the seed to a known value using `srand()`

In the read function, reset the seed using `srand()`(to the known value) and call `rand()` again. Compare this with the value that is read from disk.

Comment: @mattwolfe16 yes, if you put the same seed, you will get the exact same sequence of numbers.  The best way to think of it is, rand() pulls a number out of a large array of un-ordered numbers with every read incrementing the index, and srand() sets the index you start reading from.

Comment: So if I were to set the seed value of srand() in the read function to the same value that I did in the write function, the calls to rand() in each function would be the same for each iteration?         
  
-     writeData()                    readData()  
- Seed:       6543                          6543
- 1:   rand() = 567                   rand() = 567  
- 2:   rand() = 1264                  rand() = 1264  
- 3:   rand() = 33                    rand() = 33  
- ...

Comment: @Daboyzuk - sorry I was trying to format my comment a little nicer to no avail.

Comment: Yes, so you will *call* `srand()` only twice. But you will *call* `rand()` many times.